# Undefined Reference to Function error?

Tags: c++, function, reference, undefined

I have seen other similar questions being asked but I could not figure out what the problem is. I have a declaration in an inventory class as:

```
class Inventory
{
   Public:
      void print();
      void sell(Item*);
      void add();
      void find(string);
   Private:
      Item* first;
}
```

And then in the inventory.cpp I have:

```
 void sell(Item* item_name)
 {
    ..........................
 }
```

And the error comes from calling it in main() as:

```
Inventory store_inventory;
Item* cur_item;
cout<<"Item name: ";
string name;
cin>>name;
cur_item = find(name); //find returns Item*

store_inventory.sell(cur_item);
```

The error is one the line for the call to sell. Any ideas?

Comment: No. Find returns `void` according to your `Inventory` definition...

Answer (score 3):

The definitions need to indicate that it is a member function of `Inventory`:

```
void Inventory::sell( Item* item_name )
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, there are issues with the `find()` function. You declare it as a `void` member function, but use at as if it is a free function that returns an `Item*`.

Answer (score 0):

Is Item a class?

You should change the `void` type to the type you want to be returned `item`.

Also whem you call your sell function, at the parameter if you want to pass the same pointer, you must use the `&` before the variable name like `sell(item* &varname)`.